# Android xml: кастомные теги внутри строки

Tags: java, android, xml, строки

Как в файле strings.xml создать такую строку:

```
<string name="fullstring">
Строка, в которой содержится
<substringTypeOne> субстрока первого типа</substringTypeOne> и
<substringTypeOne> ещё одна субстрока того же типа</substringTypeOne> а также
<substringTypeTwo> субстрока второго типа</substringTypeTwo>
</string>
```

,чтобы затем в коде суметь достать как целую строку, так и субстроки всех типов:

```
System.out.println("Целая строка: "+this.getString(R.string.fullstring));

for(int i=0; i<количества substringTypeOne в R.string.fullstring; i++)
System.out.println("Субстрока первого типа номер "+i+": "+R.string.fullstring.следующаяsubstringTypeOne);

for(int i=0; i<количества substringTypeTwo в R.string.fullstring; i++)
System.out.println("Субстрока второго типа номер "+i+": "+R.string.fullstring.следующаяsubstringTypeTwo);
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
Целая строка: Строка, в которой содержится субстрока первого типа и ещё одна субстрока того же типа а также субстрока второго типа

Субстрока первого типа номер 0: субстрока первого типа
Субстрока первого типа номер 1: ещё одна субстрока того же типа

Субстрока второго типа номер 0: субстрока второго типа
```

Comment: Используйте JSOUP

Comment: Так никак. Делайте через форматирование главной строк и `string-array` для субстрок.